# elasticsearch script_score custom score function: how to replace missing values?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

I am looking at elasticsearch's documentation for how to create a script for a custom score function which uses fields that are not queried for scoring at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score) link.

From what I can see you build a script function like so:

```
"script_score" : {
    "script" : {
      "lang": "painless",
      "inline": "_score * doc['my_numeric_field'].value"
    }
}
```

but I am wondering what is the syntax for replacing `doc['my_numeric_field'].value` if it is missing?

Comment: you can place a null check for this field in the script 
    doc['my_numeric_field'].value

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing although I haven't found great documentation on what I can do here.

Comment: @user3775217 How do you make a null check ? I'm getting some errors like `cannot convert MethodHandle(Doubles)double to (Object)boolean` when I try to use ternary operators `float_can_be_null ? float : some_default`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following worked (my version is 6.2.4):

```
          "script_score" : {
            "script" : {
              "source": "doc.containsKey('my_numeric_field') ? doc['my_numeric_field'].value : 0"
            }
        },
```

Found it at:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html

Answer (score 1):

Question is old, but maybe my answer would be useful for someone.

[You should use size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-examples.html#_missing_values) in order to check if value is missing:

```
doc['field'].size() == 0
```